# Netsuite! using freemarker to get the name of the month from a date DD/MM/YYYY doesn't work

Tags: javascript, netsuite, freemarker

**Problem**

I am working on an email template text whereby I would like to change the date DD/MM/YYYY to MMMM. There are two instances of it in the template. The two instances belong to 2 different date fields however their configuration is the same. Let's say I have `date_field1` and `date_field2`. When I do the following in `date_field1` it works fine but in `date_field2` it doesn't and I get the following error.

I have checked the type of **mydate** just to make sure and it is a **date**. When I just do `?string` it works fine and it does contain a date value but with `.MMMM`, it throws an error. Any help or suggestion will be great.

**Code**

```
Working: <#assign mydate1=transaction.date_field1 /> ${mydate1?string.MMMM?lower_case}

Not working: <#assign mydate2=transaction.date_field2 /> ${mydate2?string.MMMM}
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question with examples of both `transaction.date_field1` and `transaction.date_field2`?

Comment: @JackFleeting sorry for late reply, but I have edited it just now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual date field the format string is like:

```
<#assign mydate=transaction.date_field2?date["MMMM"]>
```

And of course there is no field called `date_field2` so I assume that label is meant as a simplified example.

Note you can also try:

```
<#assign mydate=transaction.date_field2?string["MMMM"]>
```

But I think that was for a more recent version of Freemarker than Netsuite supports.

Finally you can set the overall string to date format which will be in place from the place in your code down to wherever you reset it. I found I had to set it for both date and datetime because some 'date' fields are interpreted by Freemarker as datetime even when they shouldn't be:

```
<#setting date_format="MMMM">
<#setting datetime_format="MMMM">
${transaction.date_field2}
```

Comment: with `?date["MMMM"]` I get **The string doesn't match the expected date/time/date-time format. The string was parsed was: "".** So apparently that value when converting goes empty ? and with `?string["MMMM"]` I get the same error as mentioned in the question above.

Comment: So then you need to check for content `<#if transaction.date_field2?has_content>${transaction.date_field2}</#if>`